# Fonts look thinner in gtk application when not using gnome

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, fonts, gtk, awesome-wm

The fonts in gtk applications such as emacs or gedit look thinner than in other applications when I use awesome as windows manager. Switching back to unity solve the problem.
For instance `DejaVu Sans Mono` is “less bold” in emacs than in my terminal or other application even when the size is the same.
What configuration files should I edit to solve this issue?

I found a way to circumvent the issue which only partly satisfy me:
1. Run `gnome-settings-daemon` ;
2. Hit C-c to stop the process because it does not work well under awesome ;

I do not properly understand what it does and would prefer a more reliable solution.
Sometimes I have to restart dbus with `service dbus restart` or else gnome-settings-daemon will not start.  This might be unrelated.

Comment: Fonts are customizable -- e.g., `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "black" :foreground "white" :font "Courier" :height 180)` .  Bold is `:bold t`.  There are different weights of bold -- e.g., http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for your input but what I am saying is that the normal weight looks thinner that is used to be before Ubuntu update.  I do not want normal text to appear bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if [this blog post](http://weirdfellow.wordpress.com/tag/fontconfig/) would be of any help in understanding the problem.  It's three years old, but the basic nature of the rat's nest still persists.

Since you don't have `gnome-settings-daemon` running, `xrdb` and `XSETTINGS` never pick up the hinting settings established in the GNOME dialogs.  So you'll need to fall back on `fontconfig` and setting up your own `$HOME/.fonts.conf`, at which point you're writing obtuse XML entries.  [This Arch Linux Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration#Hinting) may help you get started.

EDIT: Have a look at `/usr/share/doc/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html` on your system, which describes the gory details.  Happily, you may be able to avoid the goriest of the gory details by using some soft links.

Please be aware that I have *not actually tried* the following:

Take a look inside `/etc/fonts/conf.avail`, which contains a number of pre-made config fragments.  Of particular interest will be the files beginning with `10-*` and `11-*`, which control how font hinting and sub-pixel positioning is to be done.  Some of these are mutually exclusive; for example, you'll only want to pick one of the `10-hinting-*` fragments.

First, inside your home directory, create a directory named `.fonts.conf.d` and `cd` into it.  Next, create soft-links to the config fragments you want to enable, which might look something like:

```
ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-antialias.conf 10-antialias.conf
ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf 10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf
```

At this point, once you have linked to your preferred fontconfig fragments, it will either magically work the next time you launch a program (I think this will be the case); or you'll need to run `fc-cache` to get the system to recognize your changes; or you'll need to log out and back in to your X session (least likely).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I must admit that I have trouble to make sense out of it though.

Comment: Basically, the GNOME control panels make changes to the gconf/dconf databases.  This database is read by `gnome-settings-daemon`, which then jams the settings into the font rendering system.  If `gnome-settings-daemon` is never launched, that doesn't happen, then the font rendering system looks in the "traditional" places for config data.

Comment: One thing you might try is setting the global defaults for `fontconfig` using the oddly-named package `fontconfig-config`.  To see the current settings, run the command `debconf-show fontconfig-config`.  To change the settings, run as root:  `dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config`.

Comment: Sounds good but I lack the rights to do it here at my office.

Comment: Ah, well, then you'll have to build your own `~/.fonts.conf` or `~/.fonts.conf.d/`.

Hang on while I edit the answer...